# how to click on a link in case of webdriver(selenium2.0)

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i'm new to selenium 2.0. i'm not able to find which code we to use to click on particular link in case of webdriver..

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("url");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("UserName"));
``WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
```

now i need to click on signIn button after sometime signOut

which code i need to use to perform the above operation

Answer (score 2):

I presume the element you want to click is a `<button>`. Presuming the button has the class "signin", you could click it using the following snippet.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");

WebElement signinButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.signin"));
signinButton.click();
```

If the button has an id instead of a class, you could use this instead

```
WebElement signinButton = driver.findElement(By.id("buttonId"));
```